# Does visual studio have the html/javascript sdk that can develop the app for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hope to migrate my ios apps to wp7

I found that I need to learn more about c# .I am familiar with javascript/html.

Does visual studio have html/javascript SDKs that can develop apps for wp7 (rather than wp8)?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PhoneGap for Windows Phone](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone)